# How to locate on view on the top and center of another one?

Tags: android

How to locate one view on the top and center of another one? So I want to have an `ImageButton` and `TextView` under it but first one to be in the center and on top of second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="SOME TEXT HERE"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What if I need to have two buttons and text views in a row?

Comment: @AndroidNoob: for more columns wrapping the corrected solution into a `TableLayout` or `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight="1"` children would be the best choice.

Comment: hah lol at @rekaszeru i read his note as he literally wanted the textview BELOW (z-index) the textview. I guess its too early and I haven't had enough coffee.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, I've misunderstood the question (really bad: y instead of z-index). I remove my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to achieve this

[Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)